# Problems when loading another UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

In my app, I implemented a QR code reader that directs the app user to another View in the app after scanning any QR code.

I have two Xibs.  One is the main screen that loads up when opening the app called demoViewController.   The other is the page the app takes you to after scanning a QR code, called yViewController.

On yViewController, I masked the entire page using a UIView called sPage.  The reason why I created this UIView is because I needed to implement this code:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yViewController" owner:self options:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:sPage];
```

Thats code that takes the user to the second page after scanning.  I needed the mask UIView sPage in order to make this method work. And it does work.

However, I think this is screwing up my interface.  I had a UIImageView in my sPage View implemented via the
demoViewConroller.m using viewDidLoad:

```
[topImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"ylogoREAL.png"]];
```

The image does not show up.

Additionally, I have some code to animate my view when the keyboard comes up and hides a textfield.  This also does not work.

I know the hierarchy is right, because I use a buttonPressed method that works on the sPage View, as well as a method that closes the keyboard when touching the view.  But nothing else works.

Can anyone help me figure out why?  Im so confused :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to achieve, but I'll give it a go

How do you initialize yViewController? I believe you should be using

```
yViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

instead of creating that mask view which loads up yViewController's nib.

Update:

After looking at your code, I believe you want to show a survey page after scanning is done. There are two things you can do

Option 1 - Easier

Present a UIView to the user, using your existing UIViewController (yViewController)

```
NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Survey" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *view_to_show = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:view_to_show];
```

Bear in mind that to be able to dismiss this view later, you will need a reference to it (declare it as a property) and later you can just do [view_to_show setHidden:YES]; or removeFromSuperview

Option 2 - UIViewController option

Create a new UIViewController with your survey view and show that

```
UIViewController *vc_new = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Survey" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentViewController:vc_new animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: where should I implement that code?  In the ViewDidLoad? I tried it there and got a "expected unqualified-id" error

Comment: how did you create your yViewController? You'd have two options, you can either go with XCode templates (create a new UIViewController with Xib, or create on in storyboard) or the dynamic way, where you initialize your view controller in code, and in your case, that'd go somewhere in the code for demoViewController

Comment: I concur, just replace your current `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yViewController" owner:self options:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:sPage];` code with this...

Comment: I created it in another project using a single view template.  Then I imported the header, implementation file, the delegates, and the xib into my "demo" project.

Comment: Also, try this: `topImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ylogoREAL.png"]];`

Comment: Albert, when I do that, I get an error for "expected unqualified-id"

Comment: When you imported your files did you copy them to the destination folder?

Comment: Also were they copied to your bundle resources?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did not copy them.  The reason why I'm "pretty sure" is because my Xcode has an issue where the dialog box doesn't open when I import (a problem to solve another day).

Comment: That sucks! Click your project file in the side-bar of Xcode and go to targets and select your target then go to Build Phases and then expand Bundle Resources... are the files like the image and whatnot in there?

Comment: Ok, do the following, in your views, check that file owner has the correct view controller class. So your home view should have homeViewController as its file's owner class, and y view should have yViewController. Then check that IBOutlets are set correctly. In your case, you will not need to initialize a Xib file like that. You might want to read Apple docs on UIViewControllers

Comment: Albert, only the yViewController was copied into the bundle, which is actually the only part of the project I need.  Again, I implemented methods in my demo.m that worked for my yViewController.xib

Comment: Yes Albert the images are there. It does suck.  My Xcode is not cooperative :(

Comment: I've looked up your error `expected unqualified-id` and apparently that appears when you try to open a nonexistent function... for example if you put a semi-colon right before your curly bracket (even if it's on the previous line)

Comment: Ege, I set the yView class to demoview as instructed by a tutorial I read online.

Comment: Albert I would be happy to do so.  What is the name of that website where I can post code and link it to here with a url?

Comment: You could try JSFiddle... it's not designed for objective-c but it should still work as far as transfers go: http://jsfiddle.net/js8BF/1/

Comment: Also Albert, the topImage replacement code did not work either :(

Comment: Yes topImage code won't work because there is no difference between using [blabla setProperty:VAL] or blabla.property = VAL

Comment: Ege, I got an exception after using your first option: "'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/09500A00-78CD-414D-A653-E3A8F572BC06/yellaProto.app> (loaded)' with name 'Survey''"

Comment: You have to replace Survey with whatever view you want to show there of course, "yellaViewController" in your case I believe

Comment: oh yea! Oops!  Okay, I removed the surveyPage UIView, and just connected the survey page 'view' to the file owner in y view xib.  When I tried using your first suggestion, the program crashes. When I try using your second suggestion, the app takes me back to the original scan page after scanning a code instead of taking me to the survey.  Then I get this in the debugger: Warning: Attempt to present <UIViewController: 0x1f55c2e0> on <demoViewController: 0x1f53b6d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: I also tried using my original code, but deleting the subview part.  The app successfully takes me to the survey page, but again, with the ImageView and keyboard animation not working.  Ugghhhh :(

Comment: Whoooo finally solved it!!  All I needed to do was declare the topImage right under [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yViewController" owner:self options:nil]; .  I guess ViewDidLoad was the wrong place to put it in this case!

Comment: Ege, Albet, thank you guys so much for you patience and time!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your error correctly you are calling a function and then ending the line with a semi-colon (programmers force of habit) then going to the next line (maybe) to open the function with a curly bracket.

```
-(void) function();
{
```

It needs to not have the semicolon

```
-(void) function()
{
```

Comment: The functions are set up properly. When I get the unqualified error, the yellow curser is shown under the = sign

Comment: What is your full error... Does it say expected unqualified-id before __________?

Comment: It is "expected unqualified-id".  Also, none of the text becomes auto-colored, just the string

Comment: It appears on the line of code Ege first recommended when I try to use it

Comment: From what I understand `[super viewDidLoad];` must come first. Try moving the code that is above it to below it.

Comment: Also I don't see ege's code in your .m file I also don't even see the code you posted, `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yViewController" owner:self options:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:sPage];`

Comment: Is that your full .m file code? Did you never include your .h file at the top?

Comment: Also a lot of your code doesn't even look ilk objective-c to me... I know nothing of C++ but are you sure you aren't copying some C++ code off of the internet?

Comment: I removed ege's code because it was giving me the error.  The .h is there I just didnt copy it. Lots of this code is C++, the file you are reading is actually an .mm The reason is that it was necessary for implementing the ZXing QR Code reader

Comment: instead of "sPage", look for surveyPage, you will see the code

Comment: Ahhh! Yeah.. The only thing I know about .mm files the one time I worked with them is that you have to declare all variable transformations, they aren't automatic like they are in .m files haha! I wish I could help you but I'm at a loss... You could start a bounty for your questions once you get more site reputation...

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was declare the topImage right under [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yViewController" owner:self options:nil]; .  I guess ViewDidLoad was the wrong place to put it in this case!